# How to commit, push and clone behind a proxy

Tags: git, github, proxy

I'm behind a corporate proxy and working with GitHub. I have seen other posts about configuring the proxy settings but that doesn't work for me.

When I'm about to commit or clone a repo this is the answer of GitHub desktop, cmd in windows and cmd in linux:

> fatal: unable to connect to github.com:
>
> github.com[0: 192.30.253.112]: errno=No error
>
> github.com[1: 192.30.253.113]: errno=No error

I configured the proxy settings using the command:

```
git config --global http.proxy http://proxyuser:proxypwd@proxy.server.com:8080
```

Also I tried to configure a local proxy, or bypass my own proxy with a vpn but without results.

Do anyone has a tip or sugestion to solve this?

Thanks in advance!

PD

I'm capable of see my projects from github desktop but can't clone them.

Comment: did you also set **https**.proxy?

Comment: Yes I did, I'm able to see all my repos from github desktop but I can not clone them. I get the same response...